# Org-mode Integration with Google Calendar?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, calendar

It seems that the various methods of calendar integration have not been working well. The [tutorial on worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-google-sync.html) is outdated and the function is now called `org-icalender-export-to-ics`. However running this function on an `.org` file gives me an `.ics` file which does not have any entry:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:Personal
PRODID:-//Xiang Ji//Emacs with Org mode//EN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:HKT
X-WR-CALDESC:
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
END:VCALENDAR
```

I used to use `mobileorg` to directly sync with Google Calendar on Android. However the project has long been out of maintenance and recently I haven't been able to sync any of my org files with `mobileorg` at all, with various undecipherable errors occuring.

All I need is to sync those entries with `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE` to my calendar so that I can also check on them when I'm on my cellphone.

There has been [a similar question](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2mg1q0/syncing_between_orgmode_and_google_calendar/) on Reddit but none of the solutions mentioned there have been able to achieve this end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the reason why the exported `ics` files was empty was because I didn't customize the variables related to ical export. I had to run `customize-group` on `org-export-icalender` and change quite a few parameters. I changed `org-icalendar-use-scheduled`, `org-icalendar-use-deadline`, `org-icalendar-include-body` `org-icalendar-timezone`, `org-icalendar-store-UID`. It seems that Google Calendar would only recognize type `VEVENT` in `ics` files. `VTODO` will not get recognized, so I had to make sure that the export generates `VEVENT` from `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE` entries. I'd say the default options were a bit not user-friendly though. And those customizations seem to not be mentioned in the worg guide.

Comment: If you 1) export the ICS, 2) import into GCal, 3) reschedule an event, 4) reexport the ICS, 5) import into GCal, will that result in duplicating the rescheduled event?

Comment: @blujay No. `org-icalendar-store-UID` is there to ensure the same events get the same UID. Also there's no need to re-import. I think Google Calendar automatically checks once in a while to see whether the file is updated and thus new events are added. I store the ics file in Dropbox's `Public` folder.

Comment: Thank you.  I will have to give this a try.  If only it were bi-directional!  :D

Answer (score 3):

If you want a two-way sync with google calender, perhaps you should try `org-caldav` (https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav)? I have been using it for some time with mixed, mostly positive, results.